# Handle divide by zero with aggregated fields in Annotate expression

Tags: python, django

Currently within the following query, `win_rate` will always default to 0 unless `Lost` is 0- in that case, `win_rate` becomes 100. How do I properly allow division of the aggregated fields while avoiding the division by zero error?

```
top_markets = list(opps
                   .annotate(name=Subquery(Market.objects.filter(id=OuterRef('market'))[:1].values('marketname')))
                   .order_by('name')
                   .values('name')
                   .annotate(opps=Count('id', filter=Q(datecreated__range=(start_date, end_date))),
                             Won=Count(
                                 'id', filter=Q(winloss='Won') & Q(date_closed__range=(start_date, end_date))),
                             Lost=Count('id', filter=Q(winloss='Lost') & Q(
                                 date_closed__range=(start_date, end_date))),
                             Concluded=F('Won') + F('Lost'))
                  )
                   .annotate(
                       win_rate=Case(
                           When(Won=0, then=0),
                           default=((F('Won')) / \
                                    (F('Won')) + F('Lost'))) * 100
                       )
```

Edit-

Adding my model. `opps` is a pre-filtered query on the model `Opportunity`:

```
class Opportunity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    winloss = models.CharField()
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=SET_NULL)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Please share the models, what is `opps`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Just added my model. "opps" is a pre-filtered query.

Comment: Is doing this division in the ORM necessary? Seems like it would be simpler to loop over the responses in Python and do the division there. You already have the total of Won and Lost, so that wouldn't significantly increase the data being returned.

Comment: @NickODell: I would indeed do this in the serializer: it does not require any extra queries.

Comment: @NickODell I want to avoid looping over the data if possible- trying to keep this as efficient as possible as the number of opps and markets will likely be large.

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to a `FloatField`:

```
from django.db.models import Count, F, FloatField, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Cast


opps.values(name=F('market__marketname')).annotate(
    opps=Count('id', filter=Q(datecreated__range=(start_date, end_date))),
    Won=Count(
        'id', filter=Q(winloss='Won', date_closed__range=(start_date, end_date))
    ),
    Lost=Count(
        'id', filter=Q(winloss='Lost', date_closed__range=(start_date, end_date))
    ),
    Concluded=F('Won') + F('Lost'),
    win_rate=Case(
        When(
            Concluded__gt=0,
            then=Cast('Won', output_field=FloatField())
            * 100
            / Cast('Concluded', output_field=FloatField()),
        ),
        default=0,
        output_field=FloatField(),
    ),
).order_by('name')
```

That being said, I don't see why you do this at the database side: you have the amount of won and list `Opportunity`s, so you can just do that at the Python/Django level. Furthermore please do *not* use the queryset to generate serialized data: use a serializer.

Comment: Thanks Willem - for some reason the division by zero error still persists even with the __gt=0 condition added and the Casts added. However- I am interested in exploring how these calculations can be done within a serializer. How would I go about doing that?